# Current Induced in a Superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I am trying to solve problem 7.43 in Griffiths, where a Superconducting Sphere is cooled below its critical temperature, and I am asked to find the induced current.

In the first few parts of the question I showed that:
a) The **magnetic field is constant** inside a perfect conductor.
b) The **magnetic flux is constant** through a perfectly conducting loop.
c) The **current in a superconductor resides on the surface**.

Note that a superconductor is a perfect conductor i.e. $\mathbf E=0$ with the additional property $\mathbf B=0$. A superconducting sphere of radius $a$ is placed in a magnetic field $\mathbf B=B_0\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ and is above its critical temperature (so that means as far as I understand $\mathbf E=0$, $\mathbf B=B_0\mathbf{\hat{z}}$).

The sphere is then cooled below its critical temperature (so that means as far as I understand $\mathbf E=0$, $\mathbf B=0$). I am asked to find the induced current in terms of the polar angle $\theta$...but this is not the issue...

My question is...how on earth would this scenario be consistent with conditions (a) and (b)? The **magnetic field obviously changes** yet condition (a) says **the magnetic field is constant**. Note that condition (a) applies in a perfect conductor **regardless** of whether or not the conductor is a superconductor. This is clearly an impossibility.